# Replace a substring in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

What is a proper way to replace a part of string, matching some criteria, for example, if I have this text:

```
"some_text1((some_text2) and 1)some_text3"
```

I want to convert it into:

```
"some_text1(some_text2)some_text3"
```

In this example, the criteria is: if there is `( ... and 1)`, I want to replace it with `...` (some text, I don't know what is it).

Edit:
According to answers I've written this function:

```
static String replaceRecursive(String str, String pattern, String matcher) {
    String res = str.replaceAll(pattern, matcher);
    if (res == str) {
        return res;
    }
    return replaceRecursive(res, pattern, matcher);
}
```

usage:

```
String str = "((((X and 1) and Y) and 1) or Z)";

System.out.println(replaceRecursive(str, "\\((.*) and 1\\)", "$1"));
```

It seems to be working

**Update:**
It still doesn't work. There is problem in brackets. 
For example, if 
`str = "((some_text1)((some_text2) and 1))"`, 
the first opening bracket will be removed, instead of the third one.

Comment: What is criteria for your strings?

Comment: Replace `"some_text1((some_text2) and 1)some_text3"` with `"some_text1(some_text2)some_text3"` and you're done. Seriously though, what are the exact requirements? How many nested parenthesis can occur? What have you tried already?

Comment: criteria is ( ... and 1), and I don't know what ... is

Comment: Can `...` contain nested `and 1)` like `"some_text1(((some_text2) and 1) and 1)some_text3"`? If yes what should be the result?

Comment: the result should be "some_text1(some_text2)some_text3"

Comment: '(some_text1\()\(([^)]+)\) and 1(\)[^\n]+)' this is the regex, replace with this: '$1$2$3' - enjoy....

Comment: Wouldn't it be quicker to do this?: `replaceRecursive(str, "\\((.*) and 1\\)", "$1")`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
String s = "some_text1((some_text2) and 1)some_text3";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\(.*?(\\(.*?\\)).*?\\)", "$1"));
```

This matches nested parenthesis and puts the inner parenthesis in match group 1, which is then used in the replacement string, effectively discarding the outer parenthesis (and its contents).

Needless to say, if either `some_text1` or `some_text3` contains parenthesis, things will go wrong.